# Need advice in develop a queue job to interact between two application

Tags: asp.net, queue

Currently i have a web application and a wins form application in my server. Basically, the web application will receive request from user and this request will be send to the wins form application to proceed (wins form need about 1 minute to complete a request).

Let say 2 users send a request at the same time via web application, I need to develop a queue job to maintain the request in sequence.

1) User A make a request > request will be store into a queue job

2) User B make a request > request will be store into a queue job

3) The queue job will send the first request to the wins form. Once first request is complete, then will follow by the second request

So my question is, this queue job should be develop inside the web application? Or it should be develop in a stand alone wins form?

Any example code for create a queue job in ASP.NET?

Or anyone can suggest a better solution?

Comment: So there are automatically being sent to the form? How about a selection system on the form where new requests can be chosen and are ordered based on their time submission? (Just throwing around an alternative :D)

Comment: I assume the winform is acting as a service then the form should either poll the queue or register a listner. The Web Service should only forward the request. Your Form could be configured to use tasks so it could process more than one request at a time.

Comment: @tymeJV, The winform will execute once it receive a request from web form. The wins form will be execute automatically and no user will use it. So selection system is not an option for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jcwrequests, the win form only allow to process one request due to some limitation. Agree with the Web Service should only forward the request. But again, im not sure how to create a queue.

Comment: Well there is a [Queue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx), use `Q.Enqueue(Request)` when the winform receives a task, and loop through `Q.Dequeue` until the Queue is empty. Also suggest using a backgroundworker to keep the UI responsive and to show you how big the queue is, and possibly the status of each job.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Queue<task> Q = new Queue<task>();


public void Proccess_Request(string info)
{
    task t = new task();
    t.INFO = info;
    Q.Enqueue(task);
}

public void DoWork()
{
    //
    while (Q.Count > 0)
    {
        task t = Q.Dequeue();            
        //Process task t
    }

}


public class task
{
    public string INFO { get; set; }
    // Whatever task properties you need
}
```

You will need to build the service that accepts form data and passes it to method `Process_Request`. You will also need to call method `DoWork` either once every x minutes, or have it listen for `Process_Request` to fire.

Comment: This method looks good. But seems like it need to hard code the interval time to call the DoWork.

Comment: I didn't want to make it too confusing. DoWork would be a method called by a background worker. Just check if the background worker is "busy" before invoking it on a separate thread. You don't want DoWork running twice at the same time, and you don't want to freeze your application and not be able to accept more tasks from your website.

Comment: [Here is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-9) the code sample I refer to when using backgroundworkers.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use MSMQ and do it that way. the ASP.NET site sends a message to the queue, the winforms app (or service) is bound to the queue so when messages come into the queue, it will pick it up, process it and let it be done until no more messages in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle cross domain queue communication with MSMQ, for example.